# Identify Controls Name/ID in QT app on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, testing, spy++

I am testing a QT app on Redhat Linux and many of the controls have a graphic and not text. On windows I would use Spy++ to get the id/name of the control but not sure what to use on Linux and have not been able to find an answer on Google.

I would like to be able to say:
On screen xyz button project.com.moduleName.buttonName - is missing caption, does not do x as expected. It should have caption blah and should do xyz.

What are my options for find the name of the button without going to the source?

Comment: Maybe the answer to question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31487/is-there-a-winspy-like-tool-for-linux-x-gtk-qt can help you?

Comment: I should have added that I have read that question. While it does help with information on the general state of a window/app it does not give information on buttons/controls. Thanks though...

Comment: Why do you need button names if you don't have the source code? They are meaningless otherwise. I think you really need to tell us what you want to do. "I am testing" is **way too little detail**. For this question to make any sense, you must tell us **exactly** what you're trying to do, and why do you think button names are somehow relevant. Remember: the source code could have been obfuscated before compilation.

Comment: I am attempting to identify controls that have no labeling or caption for logging an issue against in a bug database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On windows I would use Spy++ to get the id/name of the control

Not really. Or, rather, perhaps in ancient code that still uses WINAPI controls. On modern code, Spy++ is next to useless. You'd need specialized tools for [WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1672696/1329652) and [Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4041131/1329652) applications.

Alas, you're not looking for Spy++, but for a testing application. FrogLogic's [Squish](http://www.froglogic.com/squish/gui-testing/) is the go-to tool for this, I'd think.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'd love to get some automated regression testing going but for now I have a check list of about 400 items. :(

Comment: @MichaelHobbs How would spy++-like tool help you, then? Why do you need to find names of buttons?!

Comment: @Kuda_Ober I am attempting to identify controls that have no labeling or caption for logging an issue against in a bug database

Comment: @MichaelHobbs Include a screenshot. There's no point in referring to names of controls when you have no access to the source code.